# does the word "reference sentence" make any sense?

Tags: citation

A book has a sentence 'A', which is cited from another book. In the other book, there is sentence 'A1' that 'A' is based on.

Is it correct to say that 'A1' is the **reference sentence** of 'A'?

Answer (score 1):

A 'reference N' (where N is a noun phrase) in this usage means 'an N that has been given as an example, and to which we refer back'. It's often in the same work (as [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TjirdzcZKZgC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=%E2%80%9Creference+sentence%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=gJXoY5vXNk&sig=xmZBDRH_eBkF4g0aFTnd_aYVykk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XmQMU8KqHpCV7AadmoGQBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Creference%20sentence%E2%80%9D&f=false) ) but *can* be in another work, but then this must be made clear.

> AHD has:
>
> 1. A mention of an occurrence or situation: made frequent references to her promotion.
> 2. a. A note in a publication referring the reader to another passage or source. b. The passage or source so referred to.

The usage in 'reference passage / work / sentence' is as an attributive noun.

Your example seems to be a straight quote, though. It would be more common to refer to the original occurrence as 'the original' if absolutely necessary.

Comment: so we could say "N has reference N1" or "N1 is the reference sentence of N"? is that right?

Comment: The first is a different construction, with 'reference' used as a pure noun not an attributive noun. I've just used N to represent any allowable noun / noun phrase, such as 'sentence', whereas you used A and A1 to stand for the actual quote in its first and quoted appearances.